# Xcode 7.2.1 Swift 2.1.1 cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<_,_>' to type 'Dictionary'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I updated Xcode to 7.2.1 and when compiling I'm getting the following error many times from different files.

I still get the errors even when I comment out the dictionaries I use in that file. I don't understand why it does not give me the line of the error.

[image]
An example of how I declare and use dictionaries here:

```
  var viewControllersCache = [String: UIViewController]()
  ...
  viewControllersCache["notifications"] = notificationsContainer
```

I've not had compilation problems before with previous versions of xcode/swift. Is this something to do with the build settings or have I missed something with how to declare empty dictionaries/assign values to them.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: It appears that notificationsContainer is of type `Dictionary` instead of `UIViewController`

Comment: from which version did you update to swift 2.1.1 ?? please show us the exact line of your code where you received the error ...

Comment: Try this, is the same thing  "var viewControllersCache = Dictionary<String, UIViewController>()"

Comment: @JeanLebrument it's not that. I've updated my question with more info. There's no line number for the error, the only connection I can make is I declare an empty dictionary or array, but when I comment out the possible 'offending' lines the file still flags with an error. Same issue if I try Dictionary<String, UIViewController>. It seems something is wrong in the compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found something. Looks like a bug.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20531

Solution is to declare dictionary or array explicitly e.g.

```
 var viewControllersCache:Dictionary<String,UINavigationController> = Dictionary<String,UINavigationController>()
```

So look through your code and see where you aren't doing this.

Hope this helps someone.